# How useful is dragonball saiyan armor?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

I was wondering if there are any specific details about how much damage Saiyan armor can absorb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the armor is worn more as a uniform and possibly a form of attire allowing Saiyans to fight comfortably rather than the aspect of protection simply because, their abnormal levels strength would be too difficult to provide protection from with armor comfortable enough to wear and fight in

If you were to consider Vegeta who still wears armor, it is obvious he doesn't wear the armor for protection based on his level of strength and the kind of enemies he fights. Hence, it can be considered to be more like a uniform instead of something worn for the purpose of protection.

I do understand that Vegeta has been a Saiyan Elite and he is absurdly strong at the present and a regular Saiyan's strength is significantly lesser in comparison. 
If you were to rewatch the **Sayan Saga**, this particular scene [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqeLeBziyVM), we see a Simple Slice of a sword from someone as weak as *Yajirobe*, strong enough to penetrate through Vegeta's armor and hurt him.

Saiyans are a naturally aggressive warrior race primarily focused on battle and striving to be the strongest in the Universe and I personally believe wearing the armor seems more as an outfit choice rather than focusing too much on the aspect of the protection it provides.